# Cloud9 reverse nginx proxy between 2 workspaces

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cloud9-ide

I have 2 applications running under a Cloud9 workspace. both are exposed using Ngnix as a reverse proxy. Due to the resource limitation I would like to move the backend app another workspace to have :
front end app (angular app) -> workspace 1.
back end app (NoSql engin) -> workspace 2.

But when I was testing my Nginx config, I noticied that both workspace have the same ip and there for the reverse proxy is not working.

Do you have an idea how can bypasse this constraint ?

Answer (score 0):

If both your workspaces are hosted on the same machine, then it could have the same IP. Also, Cloud9 workspaces can be moved due to various reasons to different machines, so depending on workspace IPs is not a reliable mechanism. Instead, the application url is dependable and will always point to your running server. Can you use the application server urls instead?

Comment: well I tried to use the workspace url in my Nginx config but not working either. basically :   `ping workspace1.c9.io` and `ping workspace2.c9.io` gave the same ip (public ip). but when I checked with `ifconfig` for each I have a different ip 172.17.XX.XX and 172.17.XX.XX , I have tried to use the internal ips but the error was different and it was about netwrok config 'no route ....'